# How can I create a software that makes another software? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a little question.

**SOFTWARE1**
I made a software that changes the homepage of FF and IE. The software is just opening and closing by itself, after the homepages are changed. I set the new homepage in the source code, of course I could do a text box or something like that.

**SOFTWARE2**
What I want, is to make another software ... in which I have a textbox and a button. In the textbox I will write the "new homepage URL" and after I click OK, I would like to get the **SOFTWARE1** with the "new homepage URL" that I have inputed in the first software.

This is just ... that I want to get an application, that is doing this:

-opening
-changing homepages
-closing

I don't know how to make the software that makes my other software.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: #2 writes the URL to a configuration file that the #1 reads?

Comment: that should work too, but I don't want this to use only on my computer. The ideea is to get only one file (one exe, SOFTWARE1) without any configuration/text files around it, in order to work.

Comment: would DropBox or the many similar work for you? Or put the file on a web site.

Answer (score 0):

you have only to use Process.Start
like

```
Process.Start("software1.exe", textbox.text);
```

on your software2 code

Answer (score 0):

Open SOFTWARE1 inside SOFTWARE2 by command and pass parameter to it. then inside SOFTWARE1 get parameters and set homepage by received parameter

**Inside SOFTWARE2:**

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();        
psi.FileName = "C:\SOFTWARE1.exe";
psi.Arguments = "http://stackoverflow.com";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**Inside SOFTWARE1:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "";
    if (args.Length > 0)
        url = args[0];
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new frmGetText(url));

    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

To create and compile code programmatically, look into `System.CodeDom` namespace. It will allow you to generate source code for your PROGRAM1 from PROGRAM2 and compile it into working executable.

[Here is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06) a tutorial, look into section named "Using a CodeDOM code provider to compile assemblies".